# Celery not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) when using -Ofair

Tags: celery

When I run this command

```
command: celery -A server worker -l info -Ofair — without-gossip — without-mingle — without-heartbeat
```

I get

> Reason: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Answer (score 0):

Your task take 2 arguments but you send only 1.
for example:

```
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

add.apply_async((2, 2)) #send two arguments
```